# How to get which trace is clicked in legend in plot.ly JS

Tags: javascript, plotly, onclicklistener

In plot.ly, you are able to add a listener for legend click events. How can I find out which trace in the legend I clicked? For a more concrete example, suppose I have two traces (trace0, trace1) in a line graph. When the user clicks trace0 in the legend, I want to display an alert saying "trace0". Similarly, when the user clicks trace1 in the legend, I want an alert saying something different. I can make alerts just fine but I can't find any documentation on how plot.ly identifies which trace is clicked in the legend. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-events/) about Event Handlers you can use `data`, which contains information about the event.

```
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
  type: 'scatter'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [16, 5, 11, 9],
  type: 'scatter'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);

var myPlot = document.getElementById('myDiv');

myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(data) {
    // get event information from data
    console.log(data);
});
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/iamdlm/pen/gORgjJb)

Answer (score 1):

When the legend for a certain trace is clicked, the id can be obtained from 'event.curveNumber', as seen below. The following code does exactly what the OP has asked for.

```js
const plot_container = document.getElementById("plotly-chart"); //use appropriate div id here

let data = [
  {
    x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y: [10, 12, 8, 15, 11],
    mode: "lines",
    name: "trace0",
  },
  {
    x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y: [6, 8, 4, 9, 7],
    mode: "lines",
    name: "trace1",
  },
];

let layout = {
  legend: {
    itemclick: false, // Disable default click behavior
  },
};

Plotly.newPlot(plot_container, data, layout);

plot_container.on("plotly_legendclick", function (event) {
  alert(data[event.curveNumber]["name"]);
});
```

Logging the event to the console will give more information.

```js
plot_container.on("plotly_legendclick", function (event) {
  console.log(event);
});
```